# Why does 'formData' not work in 'axios 0.26.1' in react native Android emulator?

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, expo

I have use `expo-image-picker` and `axios 0.26.1`. `formData` in `axios` version 0.26.1 isn't work. when using `formData`, data is not sent to the `api`

[image]

downgrade `axios` to version 0.24.0 but I get this error when sending formData in Android emulator.

> Error: Network Error

formData:

[image]

```
export const sendRequest = (url, response, method, formData) => {
  return axios({
    url,
    method,
    data: method !== "get" ? formData : null,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${response.data.access}`,
      transformRequest: (data, headers) => {
        return formData;
      },
    },
  });

const formData = new FormData();
const imageUri = image.value.uri;
const newImageUri = "file:///" + imageUri.split("file:/").join("");

formData.append("photo", {
  uri: newImageUri,
  type: mime.getType(newImageUri),
  name: newImageUri.split("/").pop(),
});

data.append("title", title);
```

can you help me please?

Comment: Nested headers?

Comment: How your URL Started with https or http?

Comment: @DhavalSarvaiya

For a local server to test from http
And for the main server from https but none of them work. Also this problem only exists when sending the 'formData'.

Answer (score 4):

This bug has been posted on Axios GitHub issues and apparently it is present since 0.25.0. I had to roll back to version 0.24.0 to make it work. However, this issue has been closed with the following solutions.

Method 1:

```
const formData = new FormData();
const response = await axios.post('/URL', formData, {
   headers: {
   ...formData.getHeaders()
   }
});
```

Method 2:

```
axios.post(url, formData, {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
  transformRequest: formData => formData,
})
```

[You can check the issue here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4406)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Had the same issue and I resolved this problem by downgrading to 0.24.0. Thanks for the helpful advice